# Sorting Number Columns in Order In SSRS

Tags: sorting, date, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012. In my SQL Code, I have developed a column AgeBucket which basically will calculate the number of days between a request's Start Date and End Date. My code for it is below (I apologize in advance for it's long code.)

It works and when I try to bring it into the dataset for my SSRS Report it also works, but with the columns, the numbers appear out-of-order. It shows 6-10 as the last column and all of the other columns seem to be in order when grouping by AgeBucket.  I realize that SSRS may be looking at the first number of each column and that's why 6-10 was thrown last in the sort.

My question is, how do I sort these numbers in order in SSRS? I have the column AgeBucket in my ColumnGroups but not sure best way to sort to get the information in the correct columns in order.

```
         CASE WHEN 
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 0 AND 6
         THEN '0-5'
         WHEN 
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 6 AND 10
         THEN '6-10'
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 11 AND 15
         THEN '11-15'
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 16 AND 20
         THEN '16-20'
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 21 AND 25
         THEN '21-25'
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 26 AND 30
         THEN '26-30'
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 31 AND 35
         THEN '31-35'
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 35 AND 40
         THEN '35-40'
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END > 40
         THEN '41+'
    END AS AgeBucket
    FROM CAST(A.StartDate AS DATE) = C1.[CAL_DT]        
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DT_DIM] AS C2 
    ON CAST(A.EndDate AS DATE) = C2.[CAL_DT]        
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DT_DIM] AS C3 
    ON CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) = C3.[CAL_DT]
```

Comment: For me it's not clear what you want. There is only one **correct** place to put the sorting: The outer most `SELECT`. In your final `ORDER BY` it is allowed to use given *aliases*. Another approach was to wrap the full query as `CTE` and do a `SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY col1,col2,...`. The same would work with the query wrapped as sub-select.

Comment: You mean `rows` are out of order not `columns` right ?

Comment: The code above was just more focused on explaining how I created my AgeBucket field. My main goal was when I populated this dataset field in SSRS, it wasn't showing up in order when I grouped by AgeBucket. It went "0-5", "11-15", "16-20"...and "6-10" showed up last. But the checked answer explains how to fix it, needed to sort easily in the SSRS Column Groups category.

Comment: @Searching - no, the columns were out of order...not rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - it is sorting by the first character since your field is a text field.

I would just use a **IIF** statement in the **SORT** of your Group in SSRS:

```
=IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "0-5",   1, 
 IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "6-10",  2, 
 IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "11-15", 3, 
 IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "16-20", 4, 
 IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "21-25", 5, 
 IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "26-30", 6, 
 IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "31-35", 7, 
 IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "36-40", 8, 
 IIF(Fields!AgeBucket.Value = "41+", 9, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you @Hannover, this worked and was exactly what I needed using SSRS. Appreciate you!

Answer (score 1):

You have some choices with this.

1. Change the bucket labels so that they will sort the way you like. They are text, so adding leading zeros may be what you want to do.

`'0-5'` would need to be `'00-05'`; `'6-10'` -> `'06-10'`, etc. Not that pretty.

2. Add another field in the query like the one you have for the buckets, but use numbers instead of text label. Use this new field to sort in the report.

See below. I have handled the situation as such.

```
    CASE WHEN 
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 0 AND 6
         THEN 10
         WHEN 
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 6 AND 10
         THEN 20
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 11 AND 15
         THEN 30
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 16 AND 20
         THEN 40
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 21 AND 25
         THEN 50
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 26 AND 30
         THEN 60
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 31 AND 35
         THEN 70
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END BETWEEN 35 AND 40
         THEN 80
         WHEN
            CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
                 WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
         END > 40
         THEN 100
    END AS OrderBy
```

Use the new `OrderBy` column to sort in the RDL.

3. Wrap the current query in a `SELECT` statement, and add the new column for sorting by evaluating the `AgeBucket` for it's value, and setting the proper sort order. Use the new column for sorting in the RDL like above.

See below.

```
SELECT AA.*, CASE WHEN AA.AgeBucket = '0-5' THEN 10
WHEN AA.AgeBucket = '6-10' THEN 20
...
ELSE 100 END AS OrderBy
FROM (SELECT ...,
CASE WHEN 
    CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
            WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
            WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
    END BETWEEN 0 AND 6
    THEN '0-5'
    WHEN 
    CASE WHEN A.[EndDate] > A.[StartDate] THEN C2.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]  
            WHEN A.[EndDate] IS NULL and A.[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[BusinessCalendarDay] - C1.[BusinessCalendarDay]
            WHEN A.[EndDate] = A.[StartDate] THEN 1
    END BETWEEN 6 AND 10
    THEN '6-10'
    ...
    THEN '41+'
END AS AgeBucket
...) AA -- End of wrapping SELECT
```

Good luck!

Comment: While all 3 solutions work, #1 and #2 wouldn't be necessary useful in my case. #3 did work and I appreciate you helping me answer. Only checked the above one as answer because it allowed me to simply sort in SSRS without manipulating original SQL code. But thank you and I appreciate your help!

Comment: The answer is a good solution. I tend to lean more toward changing the SQL first since I am more of a database jockey. I guess it all comes down to where you want to make changes should the buckets need to change... the RDL, or the SQL/Stored procedure. Glad to help!